# Swift tvOS use cursor for navigating and controlling tvOS application

Tags: swift, xcode, navigation, cursor, tvos

Im currently developing tvOS app and i wonder if i can just implement cursor to navigate and control my app? so i don't have to implement onFocus or like manually change from button to button using that navigation arrow from tvOS remote

Is it possible to do that? or tvOS user is force to use that onFocus to tap the button and do all the control in tv app?

Because i converting my ios app into tvOS, so theres alot of button and property that i have to convert if i want to use the onFocus, it would be easier if i can just implement cursor for user to navigate, if that even possible.

Thanks